# Proyecto Swift 2 sin StoryBoards

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode

Querría crear un proyecto en Swift 2 en el cual no se trabaje con `storyBoards` ya que en Objective-C estoy acostumbrado a trabajar con `XIBs`.

Hace un tiempo estuve probando con Swift 1.x y recuerdo que para asignarle el VC al `rootViewController` en el `appDelegate` había que primero (al igual que Objective-C)

- crear una instancia del VC:

  `let vc = ViewController(nibName:"ViewController", bundle:nil)`
- luego asignarla al `rootViewController`

Mi problema reside en que al declarar la constante `vc` me salta el siguiente `warning`:

```
Immutable value 'vc' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it
```

¿Podría alguien darme alguna indicación?

Comment: Estás seguro de estar usando `vc` después de crearla?

Comment: Gracias! era eso, me despistaba el guión bajo, en Objective-C simplemente te sale el warning y te dice que tu variable o constante no ha sido utilizada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aquí los pasos:

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

let vc = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
self.window?.rootViewController = vc
```

Por cierto, muy buena elección no utilizar Storyboards ;)